# GUI harness for MFC DLL?

Tags: c++, user-interface, dll, mfc

I have a CWinApp-based application that is built as a DLL that is loaded by another 3rd party application as a plugin.  My app exposes an exported StartPlugin() method that creates a CDialog derived dialog.  This exported function is somehow called by the 3rd party application.  I'd like to be able to run my DLL outside of the 3rd party application so I can test and play around with UI stuff (not for unit testing).

How can I create a test harness that will allow me to run my dll code?  I'm not sure how the main application launches my dll plugin, but I'm speculating that it's creating a User-Interface thread?  So would I just need to create a simple exe that can somehow load my dll and create a new thread or something.  Any links to tutorials or articles that explain something like this.

Comment: I'm surprised that if you have a MFC DLL that you don't already know how to do this yourself. You already know how to start your plugin, you do it by calling StartPlugin.

Comment: I am having difficulty doing the same, starting and running a CWinApp derived from a different DLL. What do you do in your StartPlugin to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Visual Studio wizard to create a MFC application, probably Dialog based. Have a button on the dialog to run your plugin. In the button code do a LoadLibrary with the name of your DLL, then call GetProcAddress to get a pointer to the StartPlugin function. Then you can call StartPlugin.

Comment: Found this article which suggest same thing: [How to load a dynamic link library (DLL) into a Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/loadingdll.aspx) I'm going to give it a try and report back.

Comment: This worked.  Now I need to decouple my app from the dependencies on the 3rd party app.